# Access denied for root MySQL user to DB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

As root MySQL user in phpMyAdmin, I ran:

```
GRANT INSERT ON db.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost'
```

And received:

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' to database 'db'

I am not understanding why root is not able to grant this permission to a db user.

Comment: So you typed the GRANT command, and immediately got the 1044 error message? Or you typed the GRANT command, it executed successfully, and then you tried logging in as db_user and it gave the the 1044 command?

Comment: I typed the GRANT command as above and immediately got the 1044.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't running as root; you're logged in as db_user. Maybe this is an issue with your browser session. Logout and log in again as root, then re-run the command

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dbaccess_denied_error

Worst case, try another browser.

Comment: For clarity the user name mentioned in the error is the currently logged in user, in this case it happens to be the same as the user you are trying to assign permissions to which is resulting in the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

John, considering the response you got :

## 1044 - Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' to database 'db'

it's obviously, as Devin stated, that you executed the query being connected as "db_user" and not as the "root" user.

Try to login again as a root and when connected double check that the user root is connected indeed, by checking the "Database Server" infos on the right side of the main phpmyadmin window. You should see something like this :

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.5.44 (Server Version/type)
- Protocol version: 10
- **User: root@localhost**
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

To check the privileges that the current user has execute :

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

I guess that you are aware that a users' privileges can be global or database-specific ( have to do with the selected database only)

In any case you feel uncomfortable using the sql command line, it is much easier to grant the desired privileges by doing the following :

If you want to grant some **global privileges** to users,do the following :

1. Login to phpMyAdmin from your web browser as a **root**
2. Click on the Users tab (do not select any database from menus )
3. Find the user you want to edit and click “Edit Privileges”
4. Select any privileges that you desire to grant.
5. Click “Go”

For **database-specific privileges** only, follow steps 1-3, mentioned above  but then :

1. Scroll down a little further until you see the “Database-specific privileges” header.
2. from the drop down menu, select the database on which you want to add privileges for the user and type the hostname (default is % for all)
   3.Click “Go”

Be sure to verify that the header reads that you are granting privileges for the specific database you are referring.
(e.g Edit Privileges: User 'db_user'@'localhost' - Database db )

4. Check the privileges you want to grant
5. Click “Go”

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: You're right. I'm not logged in as root. I have to figure out how to log-in as root user through bluehost, my hosting provider.

Comment: @JónÁrnason Jon, your hosting provider has an explanatory video posted on their domain already, describing the process of creating a new user, assigning him to a database and, finally, define the desired privileges .The link is (https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/6) and on the top of the page you will see a video showing the process with details. It is only 2 minutes long, give it a try.